# Rails rabl - returning ALL attributes, not just named ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

Rabl allows you to grab the attributes by naming them in your view, for instance:

```
object @user
attributes :name, :email
```

I have a model whose attributes are will not be known, but I'd like to display everything returned from the controller in my instance variable using rabl.

Is there a shortcut like:

```
attributes :all
```

etc.

Thanks

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this, but for future readers https://github.com/rails/jbuilder is awesome, easy to use, and allows for very quick and easy building of json objects.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to use `.column_names`:

```
attributes *User.column_names
```

Comment: This is the only answer that I've been able to find.

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to call column names on an instance of a user Model. I can call column_names on the User model in the console, but not on a particular instance of the model.

Comment: You're correct, it's a class method - fixed.  Alternatively, you can call `.class` if you can't be sure of the model class: `*@user.class.column_names`

Comment: This works for descendants of ActiveRecord::Base, but what if you are passing a different object into your RABL template, like an OpenStruct?

Comment: For OpenStruct use `attributes *@user.instance_variable_get("@table").keys`.  Any data model should have a way for you to get a list of all data attributes - you just may need to dig a bit to find them.  Then apply the solution accordingly.

Comment: Plus it taught me a bit more about the asterisk operator :)

Comment: collection @my_collection

attributes *@my_attributes.instance_variable_get("@table").keys                   But I get the following error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass).

But the same would work for a single object, not for a collection. How to make it work for a collection ?

Comment: @Raul: What object is `@my_attributes` and why do you think it would have a `@table` instance variable?  My recommendation for OpenStruct was assuming you used an OpenStruct object (`@user` in my case).

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error. What I meant was *@my_collection.instance_variable_get("@table").keys. This doesn't work for a collection but works for objects. what could be the workaround for collection then ?

Comment: @Raul: You should use a partial to change the scope to a single object, and then use the aforementioned approach.  Alternatively (and a bit of a hack), you can grab the first item in your collection and check that - this, of course, assumes that you have items in your collection.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get rid of some columns, like "created_at" and "updated_at":

```
attributes *User.column_names - ["created_at", "updated_at"]
```